# Get listview data while checked and pass it to another activity

Tags: android

Ive been searching for the right answer but nothing can solve my problems. I have a list view which is populated by my database from webserver. So basically what need is to get the data from the listview that is checked by user and pass the data to another activity. Sorry for my bad english hope you guys can help me.

Error ive received

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>                         at firin.myuploads.Attendance$1.onClick(Attendance.java:74)

**Attendance.java**

```
public class Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {
//For Checkbox
ArrayList<String> selectedItems=new ArrayList<>();

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;
private CheckBox cb;
private Button bGet;
//private id[] id;


private static String url = "www.myphpurl.com";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    bGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    new GetContacts().execute();

    bGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
     //       String selected =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);
            cb.setChecked(true);

            int len = lv.getCount();
            SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (checked.get(i)) {
                    String item = selectedItems.get(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /*some code to save data in MainActivity*/
                    Intent in = new Intent(Attendance.this, SendMail.class);
                    in.putExtra("ListValue", item);
                    startActivity(in);}


        }
    });

}
```

This is the code where i populate my data to the listview

```
 public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray result = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("userID");
                    String studentName = c.getString("studentName");
                    String parentName = c.getString("parentName");
                    String parentEmail = c.getString("parentEmail");


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("UID", id);
                    contact.put("sName", studentName);
                    contact.put("pName", parentName);
                    contact.put("pEmail", parentEmail);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }



        return null;



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Attendance.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Attendance.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"sName", "pName",
                "pEmail"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

Is this how i set my setOnClick?

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String selected =((TextView)findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);
            cb.setChecked(true);


        }});
```

Hope you guys can help me. thanks in advance

Comment: please check that your `contactList` array is null or not. Other thing is you should use `lv.setOnItemClickListener()` to get which item is selected in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get how many item is selected in the listview, then after store in another array and pass that array to another activity.

Set you listview selection mode as Multi Choice.

```
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Set Listener on listview as below

```
ArrayList<String> selectedItem = new ArrayList();
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    adapter.getView(position, view, parent).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btn_login));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Selected Item is " + stateList.get(position));
                    selectedItem.add(yourArray.get(position))
                }
            });
```

you can invok your intent and pass selectedItem to that intent like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, YourActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selected_list", selectedItem);
startActivity(intent);
```

and In your receiving intent you need to do:

```
ArrayList<String> selectedItem;

Intent i = getIntent();  
selectedItem = i.getStringArrayListExtra("selected_list");
```

Comment: ive tried your code but i dont understand the "adapter" part. Thank you very much for replying

Comment: It's Adapter object. In your case you can see in `doInBackgroud()` that is adapter. You can declare that in global so you can use that in `listview.setOnItemClickListener()`

Comment: im sorry, i am very new to android and i still dont get it sir. In my '`doInBackground()` i have no adapter. But it is in my `onPostExecute()`